# get the size of relative layout declared in xml

Tags: android

This is my xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        />

        <ImageView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_below="@+id/@+id/header"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/view" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
     >
     </RelativeLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/footer" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"    
     android:background="@android:color/white"     
     >
        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"   
        android:text="btn1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        />

        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"   
        android:text="btn2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

        <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"   
        android:text="btn3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

     </RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

the relative layout view is in between the two layouts.
I want to get the size of this relative layout(i.e height and width) in my code.I tried it by using getWidth and getHeight but it is showing 0.
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidResizeView extends Activity {

    TextView textMyTextView;
    Button myButton;

    RelativeLayout rlayout;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hightk);

        rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlayout);

        textMyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                updateSizeInfo();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        updateSizeInfo();
    }

    private void updateSizeInfo() {

        textMyTextView.setText(String.valueOf("Width: "
                + rlayout.getWidth() + "height ::" + rlayout.getHeight()));

    }

}
```

Comment: this way it's not giving me the result

Answer (score 0):

In my case I created my own custom view extending from RelativeLayout and adding a listener for onSizeChange events.

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public static interface SizeChangeListener {
        void onSizeChanged();
    }

    private SizeChangeListener mListener;

    public MiRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MiRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MiRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onSizeChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setOnSizeChangeListener(SizeChangeListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

}
```